# What do "Out of Scope" and "Out of context:" mean in OWASP ZAP?

Tags: owasp, zap

I have done automatic scan of my application. Unfortunately, I have found that on the list of URL after scanning there are some GET requests to the URIs which are flagged with "Out of Context" or "Out of Scope". Should I be affraid that I have done something illegal?

Answer (score 3):

No, not at all :) We have to be very careful with ZAP scans, partly due to legal reasons but also so that we dont try to try to scan the whole internet :)
This is typically a problem with the 2 spiders as they explore stuff, the active scanner just attacks what you've already found.

The scope is typically the domain you started the spider on. If you start spidering https://www.example.com then the spider wont start spidering https://www.google.com even if there is a link to it - that way we would end up trying to spider the internet :P

The context you define - you can think of it as an application, or part of an application, but its really just 2 sets of regexes - ones which are used to include or exclude urls. If you define a context then ZAP wont go outside of it.

ZAP doesnt know about the legal side - maybe you are employed by Google in which case you might be allowed to attack google.com, but maybe not. ZAP doesnt know that.

Comment: @SimonBennets, thanks a lot for your fast answer! Just to clarify - so if I set up in "Automated Scan" mode "URL to attack" as http://localhost:3000, all of those URIs which are marked as "Out of Scope" had not been attacked, but only requested by ZAP (with simple GET)?

Comment: They've not even been requested by ZAP. Thats unless you use the Ajax Spidr which will perfrom GETs on javascript and CSS files otherwise the app might not work. In any case, ZAP will not attack URLs other than those under the one you specified.